# Which way do you reset magento orders?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, database, mysql, sql

Which way do you reset magento orders?

For example, now the current order - # 100000051.

**I need:**

```
1) completely remove all orders from the Database 
2) new order will have to start with a number # 100000001 (this is important)
```

Please let us know your trusty and checked up way!
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this query in your database,you get expected result

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

##############################
# SALES RELATED TABLES
##############################
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;           
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;       
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

#########################################
# DOWNLOADABLE PURCHASED
#########################################
TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;

ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

#########################################
# RESET ID COUNTERS
#########################################
TRUNCATE `eav_entity_store`;
ALTER TABLE  `eav_entity_store` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: @GOOD works .give u upvote

Comment: Thanks for a great solution! 
But which version of magento community meets your solution? v.1.8 or 1.9? 

I applied your commands to my database in SSH (Putty) and my problem is solved. 
But a number of commands are in error: ERROR 1701 (42000): Can not truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`db_name`.`sales_payment_transaction`, CONSTRAINT `FK_DA51A10B240XXXXXXXXXXXX` FOREIGN KEY (` payment_id`) REFERENCES `db_name`

These are: 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;

Comment: put this code directly in your database check. It works for me correctly.I tried it in 1.7 and 1.8.

Comment: put this code directly in sql in your database check. It works for me correctly.I tried it in 1.7 and 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Use `third party extension` for delete `all orders from magento system`:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/orders-eraser.html
Or
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

Then truncate `sales_flat_order or sales_flat_order_grid` or rest increment field value  using mysql query